# plotly.js - How to fix space between bars in barchart

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, plotly

Is there any configuration layout option to increase the space between the bars in a bar plot in plotly.js ?

I tried increasing the width of the plot but it is expanding the plot as a whole.I need to fix the width of the bar and space between the bars.

Any help would be highly helpful.

Answer (score 5):

It is a setting of layout The key value pair for the layout object to change the gap is `bargap`. For example given arrays `x` and `y`:

`Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', [{x:x, y:y, type:'bar'}],{title:'title',xaxis: {title: 'abscissa'},yaxis:{title:'ordinate'},bargap:0});`

Will generate a plot with no gap like a histogram.

Comment: Unless you change the width of the bars aswell. Tried having smaller bars with no gap (width : 0.5 and bargab : 0) and it didn't work.

Comment: Also note that bargap is a float between 0 and 1. A value of 0 will give you bars with no space between them. A value of 0.5 will make bars and the space between them of equal size. And 1 will give oyu just space, no visible bar. So the value should never be equal to 1.